# Recognition - acknowledgement - best word

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-difference, word-in-context

In some cities around the world people like to have other people recognize that they have done good deeds and are therefore worthy of other people's approval and esteem. I would like to know if there is a word in English for recognition as in small-scale fame for doing good things. I am looking for a word that does not also have the recognition meaning as in say, looking at the a picture of the sun and saying to oneself, "yes, this is indeed the sun", as this is not the form of recognizing I'd like to deal with.

Comment: "small-scale *game* for doing good things"? A typo for *fame*? And by "word" are you looking for a noun? a verb?

Answer (score 1):

On the probability that you're looking for a single noun (or a phrase) that means "someone who is famous on a small scale"...

The phrase **local hero** is applied to someone whose actions were very beneficial to the immediate community but whose fame and recognition do not extend beyond that.

Comment: I like it, but the term hero really means someone that stands out front the rest, and seems somewhat inflated for what I'm looking for. Is there a similar word, similar to hero, but which describes the same thing but is of a somewhat lower rank than as hero? What if I'm seeking a word that could be applied, say, to 20% to 50% of people in a group. These people would stand out for their good deeds, and rejoice I others acknowledging their deeds, each in their own single way. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a word for this in your own language? A word that refers to the recognition 20-50% of the people in a group receive for their contributions?